# Expected value of a product of random variables

Tags: expected-value

Knowing the distribution,

\begin{array}{c c c c}
& \quad    &X=1\quad   &X=-1\quad  &X=2  \\
&Y=1\quad  &0.25\quad  &0.25\quad  &0    \\
&Y=2\quad  &0\quad     &0\quad     &0.5
\end{array}

How does one calculate E(XY)?

Comment: If this is for some course, please add the `self-study` tag. If it isn't self-study, please explain the context in which your question arises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\displaystyle E[XY] = \sum_i\sum_j x_i\cdot y_j \cdot P\{X = x_i, Y = y_j\}$
which gives $2$ in this case.

Comment: I wonder which part of the answer the down-voter believes to be incorrect or not useful.